# how can i print out the generator object without using the shell?

Tags: python, graph, depth-first-search, brute-force, function-calls

Came across this example online, its a dfs function which finds all the cycles within a graph.

I'm trying to add the cycle part into the function so i don't have to use the shell to get the results. 
I'm new to generator objects so I'm not sure how to display cycles.

version which uses the shell:

```
def dfs(graph, start, end):
    fringe = [(start, [])]
    while fringe:
        state, path = fringe.pop()
        if path and state == end:
            yield path
            continue
    for next_state in graph[state]:
        if next_state in path:
            continue
        fringe.append((next_state, path+[next_state]))

>>> graph = { 1: [2, 3, 5], 2: [1], 3: [1], 4: [2], 5: [2] }
>>> cycles = [[node]+path  for node in graph for path in dfs(graph, node, node)]
>>> len(cycles)
7
>>> cycles
[[1, 5, 2, 1], [1, 3, 1], [1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 5, 2], [2, 1, 2], [3, 1, 3], [5, 2, 1, 5]]
```

Here is my attempt:

```
def dfs(g, start, end):
    fringe = [(start, [])]
    while fringe:
        state, path = fringe.pop()
        if path and state == end:
            yield path
            continue
    for next_state in g[state]:
        if next_state in path:
            continue
        fringe.append((next_state, path+[next_state]))
    cycles = (list([node]+path for node in g for path in dfs(g, node, node)))
    print("cycles",cycles)
return path

dfs(graph, 1, 1)
```

tried several different start and end nodes all the same result.

my graph is the same as above,

```
 graph = { 1: [2, 3, 5], 2: [1], 3: [1], 4: [2], 5: [2] }
```

output = 
     generator object dfs at 0x000001D9CB846EB8

Any ideas?

Comment: if you cast a generator to a list using `list()` you can then print that list as usual. Be aware though that the cast will evaluate the entire generator object, meaning you will lose the lazy evaluation of generators.

Comment: Could also `print(*your_generator)` using the [`*splat`](http://pynash.org/2013/03/13/unpacking/) operator.

Comment: @chrisz but it consumes it.

Comment: can you fix your indentation?

Comment: wait: you're using `yield` and `return` in your `dfs` function??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def dfs(g, start, end):
    fringe = [(start, [])]
    while fringe:
        state, path = fringe.pop()
        if path and state == end:

            yield path
            continue
        for next_state in g[state]:
            if next_state in path:
                continue
            fringe.append((next_state, path+[next_state]))


graph = {1: [2, 3, 5], 2: [1], 3: [1], 4: [2], 5: [2]}
cycles = [[node]+path for node in graph for path in dfs(graph, node, node)]
print(cycles)
```

you dont need a return in a generator so you can just loop through it using a list comprehension or a regular loop.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please fix your indentation.

I think your problem is the result of missing `[]` for list comprehension to work.

Try changing the line 
`cycles = (list([node]+path for node in g for path in dfs(g, node, node)))` to  `cycles = [[node]+path for node in g for path in dfs(g, node, node)]`